What is のではと? What nuance does it add?
これから選択肢が増えていく中で自分が留めてしまうのではと迷う時もあったけどあれこれ考えるのはやめた
I understand what the sentence means. But I'm confused about a thing: What is のではと here?
自分が留めてしまうと迷う時 times were I doubt myself that I'll stop but what does のでは add?

のでは here is short for のではないか.

これから選択肢が増えていく中で「自分が留めてしまうのではないか」と迷う時もあったけどあれこれ考えるのはやめた

